# DVC get problems with the url

Tags: git, url, dvc

I'm trying to obtain the diamonds.csv dataset contained [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/tree/main/data-raw) trough dvc get using

`$ dvc get https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2 \ data-raw/diamonds.csv -o data/dataset/diamonds.csv`

But I obtained the following error:

[image]

Which summarise should be: **failed to get ... from ... Failed to clone repo ...**

Reading the documentation of dvc get-url (yes I know that I started with get, but trying also get-url I had the same problem) [here](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/get-url) I found out the command ‘dvc ls-url‘ which, as stated in the documentation [here](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/list-url) should help you see what's inside a particular url and checked with my url: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2 running
`$ dvc ls-url https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2`
And I get the following error:

[image]

Which summarised is **the path ... does not exists: ... . Cannot connect to host ...**
I tried also changing the url with another one provided in the documentation and still get the same error:

[image]

In case anyone was wondering the urls actually exists: https://github.com/iterative/example-get-started.
dvc is correctly installed on my pc.
If anyone has any idea it would be very appreciated!

Comment: get-url and ls-url don't work with git repositories and are not meant to. You are trying to get and list a git repo with dvc, so you should use `dvc get/ls`. Running `dvc ls https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2` and `dvc get https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2 data-raw/diamonds.csv -o data/dataset/diamonds.csv` both work fine for me with 2.41.1 Maybe you are behind a proxy/firewall or there was some network issue? Does `git clone` work for that repo for you?